# JQuery - Give every <div> inside a <div> an ID (array?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation, thumbnails

**Day 2**

The html...

```
<div id="galleria">
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_impfstoffbehaelter.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_impfstoffbehaelter.jpg" ></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_abfuellnadel.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_abfuelllnadeln.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_impfstoffbehaelter.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_impfstoffbehaelter.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_impfstoffverteiler.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_impfstoffverteiler.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_luftverteiler.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_luftverteiler.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_praezisionsaufnahme.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_praezisionsaufnahme.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_praezisionshalter.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_praezisionshalter.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_schlauchreduzierung.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_schlauchreduzierung.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_setzrohr.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_setzrohr.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_triclamp_verschluss.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_triclamp_verschluss.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_verschluss_adapter.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_verschluss_adapter.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_winkelreduzierung.jpg"><img src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_winkelreduzierung.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="images"><a href="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/image_zangenhalter.jpg"><img  src="../Bens_Internet_Erik/bens_img/thumbnail_zangenhalter.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Get every div inside a div and add them to an array. They should have all an ID so that I can say:

```
On click Div with ID="1" 
do this
```

This is for an thumbnail navigation.. My task is to synchronize some div content and I need a way to ask which thumbnail (div) was clicked..

**////////////////////////////////////////**

It should be like: "Hey! You are #1, you #2, you the #3, #4, #5, youre 6#, youre the #7, #8, #9, sir youre the #10, #11, #12 youre the last .. the #13.

An then this: "Okay.. I clicked thumbnail #4 .. so I fadein the CONTENT for #4 (Whicht contains a caption and some information - its basicly a very width div which will be scrolled at a position (the rest will no be shown, thanx to the overflow:hidden)). And If I click thumbnail #8 the it will show the content for the #8.

Comment: I'm not sure but i believe you can get this done through `<div id = "images[]">`

Comment: more like <div id="01" class="images"><a hr... is this possible to.. umm attract this?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, to answer your question, something like this:

```
$("#galleria div").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).attr("id", "galleria" + index);
});
```

should do the trick.

But, that being said, there are better ways to do what you are trying to do, by using things like the "eq" traversing method, ":eq" selector, and "inArray" utility method.

*** EDIT ***

To clarify how each works here's a fake/simplified version of it:

```
function each(callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        // next line is the same as callback(i, elements[i]), except it sets "this"
        callback.call(elements[i], i, elements[i]);
    }
 }
```

As you can see the callback you provide gets called whether you use the arguments or not ... but they'll always get passed to it regardless.

Comment: +1 shouldn't use just a number as the ID since that's invalid, some prefix would work.

Comment: This helped me too, but can you explain function(index, value) please....I didn't define index and value variables but it still worked for me in my case.

Comment: When you call each, it's just like any other function call: you're passing it an argument, and this case that argument is a function.  jQuery will go through *each* element in the set, and it will call the function you gave it.  When it does, it will pass the index and the current element as arguments to the call; it will also set "this" to the current element.  You don't have to use either argument (or `this`) if you don't want, but they'll always be provided in the function call.

Comment: I'll add a quick simplified version of `$.fn.each` to my answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var $divs = $("#galleria div");
```

or to get which thumbnail was clicked you could write:

```
$("#galleria .images a").click(function(e) {
    // might want to do this unless you actually want to navigate away
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // href of the anchor clicked pointing to the full size image
    $(this).attr("href");        

    // which thumbnail was clicked
    $(this).find("img");        
});
```

and if you just want to attach some ID to each div you could write:

```
$("#galleria div").each(function(index, value) {
    $("div").attr("id", "thumbnail_" + index);
});
```

Comment: $("#galleria div").each(arr.push($(this));

Comment: yeah, I see that he mentioned "array" but I don't know if that's what he really wants

Comment: $(this).find("img");  ? And whats the output? an Integer?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the this refence inside the event handler with [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
<div id="galleria">
   <div id="images">
      <div class="image">
         <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
   <div id="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumbnail">
         <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var $galleria = $("#galleria");

$galleria.on('click','.thumbnail',function(event){
   var thumb, image;
   // Index of div that user clicked...
   $thumb = $(this);
   // get the corresponding image...
   $image = $galleria.find('#images .image').eq(thumb.index());

});
```